# Mysql php hide show db value

Tags: php, mysql

I am just learning php

I have 2 divs

```
<div id="app1">stuff here</div>
```

and div 2

```
<div id="app2">stuff here</div>
```

I have an id in users table that is either 1 or 2, by default its 1,

I want to hide the divs based on a field called `users.app_id`. If `app_id` equals 1 show div `app1`, if `app_id` is 2 then show div `app2`

database is `users`

dB field is app_id

looking to learn a php way instead of jQuery or java

oh and if there any good books you think I should read please let me know.

Comment: Do you have any PHP code that we can look at?

Comment: `<div style="display:none">`

Comment: no that's why I posted here trying to learn how to do it.

Comment: yea splash58 that hides it using css but I need it to hide based on value in the database as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

To access your database using PHP, the preferred method is to use PDO. [Check out the PHP documentation on PDO here.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)

To create a new PDO connection, do something like this:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8mb4', 'username', 'password');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

Once you have a valid PDO connection, you can do a simple select query like this:

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table');
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This pulls all your results into the PHP `$results` array. Then do fun things with it from there using PHP.

If you're in a PHP file and want to render PHP code into HTML, you can do something like this:

```
$test = "<div>random HTML goes here</div>"
echo $test;
```

Since you don't have any attempt at code, I'll just leave this here to get in hope that it gets you started.

I recommend checking out some beginner level online tutorials to give you some experience using PHP. Otherwise, this question is waaaay to open-ended.